# *ngIf hide some content on mobile screen, Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have:

```
showHide: false;

<div *ngIf="showHide">
  Content
</div>

<button (click)="showHide = !showMap">
  Button visited only max-width: 768px
</button>
```

On MAX-width: 768px, I have a button. On MIN-width: 768px the button is hidden.
When I click on the button - it shows a DIV.
It works fine.

BUT

How do I make *ngIf work only when MAX-width: 768px?

max-height: 768px

- button is display: block
- DIV is display: none (but when I click on the button = display:
  block)

min-height: 768px:

- button is display: none
- DIV is display: block

At the moment when I resize from example 500px to 1000px:
It depends on button I pressed

Comment: That's better done via CSS than with Angular, just use a media query to hide the element.

Comment: No CSS. At the moment when I resize from example 500px to 1000px: It depends on button I pressed, and MIN-height; 768px - showHide is false SO i dont have DIV content

Comment: When 500px I dont click on the button - I dont have a DIV.
But when I resize to 1000px - I dont have DIV, but I want DIV on min-height: 768px. *ngIf hide DIV until you click on the button. BUT I want HIDE DIV on 500px, BUT I want to SHOW DIV on 1000px

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use window.screen.width.
Example:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (window.screen.width === 360) { // 768px portrait
    this.mobile = true;
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<button *ngIf="mobile" (click)="showHide = !showMap"></button>
```

Comment: Awesome! That's what I mean! Thank you! <3

Comment: Depending on your use case, if the user is able to resize the window this will not be responsive when they do so.  You will need to add a resize listener and recalculate on each resize.

Comment: This is only a solution for the phone which have an none responsive browser.

Comment: But it is hiding my content on desktop size width. So this must be addressed as well!

Answer (score 35):

For future me or others if you need a solution that monitors the screen size and are using Observables/rxjs then this solution works:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Checks if screen size is less than 1024 pixels
  const checkScreenSize = () => document.body.offsetWidth < 1024;

  // Create observable from window resize event throttled so only fires every 500ms
  const screenSizeChanged$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize').throttleTime(500).map(checkScreenSize);

  // Start off with the initial value use the isScreenSmall$ | async in the
  // view to get both the original value and the new value after resize.
  this.isScreenSmall$ = screenSizeChanged$.pipe(startWith(checkScreenSize()))
}
```

Comment: debounce might be more appropriate, not sure if throttle fires after the chain of events has completed

Comment: thanks for your answer. helped me a lot. debounceTime do work better. in angular7 the code has changed a bit. it's now         const screenSizeChanged$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(debounceTime(500)).pipe(map(checkScreenSize));

Comment: Instead of a concatenation of `.pipe()` you can simply use a comma as separator:  `fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(debounceTime(500), map(checkScreenSize));`

Answer (score 21):

Thought I would add this to the question as I found in this particular situation `@angular/flex-layout` to be very helpful. https://github.com/angular/flex-layout.

In particular you might be interested in the `fxHide` feature: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxHide-API but this package makes working with a responsive application much easier in my opinion.

You can show or hide content like so.

*Doesnt show when 'small' or greater than 'medium' resolutions*:

`<div fxShow.sm="false"  fxShow.gt-md="false" fxShow="true" ></div>`

*Only hides when at medium resolution*

`<div fxShow fxHide.md ></div>`

The breakpoints can be custom but they have default ones already set.

Comment: This is great, and it may be worth noting that this is not the equivalent of *ngIf, but rather [hidden].

Answer (score 14):

The least lines solution:

In your TS file:

```
public isMobileLayout = false;
ngOnInit() {
  window.onresize = () => this.isMobileLayout = window.innerWidth <= 991;
}
```

In HTML template:

```
<div *ngIf="isMobileLayout">This is visible only on mobile</div>
```

Edit: 
Also, you can detect mobile using the following code:

```
public get isMobileAgent() {
    const agent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || (window as any).opera;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    return (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(agent) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(agent.substr(0, 4)));
}
```

This might be helpful to initialize `isMobileLayout` value before any resize happens:

```
public isMobileLayout = isMobileAgent;
```

Or:

```
<div *ngIf="isMobileLayout || isMobileAgent">This is visible only on mobile</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the initial value correctly as well. i.e. when it's first loaded on mobile and there is no resize event, isMobile is still false and you get the non-mobile layout.

Comment: @RyanD yes, I did that already in my real code, I'll add this part to answer.

Answer (score 8):

Just came across this answer and I wanted something that worked responsively as well as on-resize. I set 992px as the breakpoint because I'm also using bootstrap `lg` breakpoints concurrently.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  isMobile = false;
  getIsMobile(): boolean {
    const w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    const breakpoint = 992;
    console.log(w);
    if (w < breakpoint) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isMobile = this.getIsMobile();
    window.onresize = () => {
      this.isMobile = this.getIsMobile();
    };
  }
}
```

Then in the HTML

`<div *ngIf="isMobile === true>Some mobile element!</div>`

Comment: Thank you Reed. Worked perfectly. I combined your exact code above with a routerLink to hide the header when the cart is open on mobile.

<div class="header-main" *ngIf="!(isMobile && router.url ==='/cart')">

Comment: I like this one, I updated the if-else in getIsMobile method for `return width < breakpoint`

Answer (score 3):

This works when you resize the browser window

```
@HostListener("window:resize", [])
  onResize() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    this.mobile = width < 992;
  }
```

Comment: Update the if/else statement for `this.mobile =width < 992;`

Comment: Note that this piece of code will only kick-in when user resizes the window. So, if you bind the result to your template it may not result in desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

the best route IMO is the media query route in CSS :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  #my-content { display: none; }  /* hide it on small screens */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another method that will continue to look for window changes.

```
<div class="row">
<img class="mx-auto logo" src="">
</div>
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 490px) {
  .logo{
    width: 30vh;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 491px) {
  .logo{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In TS file:

```
  isMobile() {
    const width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    return width < 768;
  }
```

And in HTML template

```
<button *ngIf="isMobile()">...</button>
```