# Using proper CSS media queries in Angular

Tags: css, angular, media-queries

I read that in Angular it is a very bad practice to use the `CSS` hidden element to hide an element like this:

```css
.container{
  background-color : powderblue;
  height : 50px;
  width : 100%
}

@media (max-width: 400px){
    .container{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

And I know the Angular way to show or hide an element is using the `*ngIf` directive.

### Question

How can I get the `* ngIf` to react on the media query in an 'Angular fashion'?

Comment: If you just need to hide something for responsive design(not hiding based on user action) then use CSS. Angular only comes in if you have interactions that need to show/hide elements. From the look of your code, you just want to hide it for 400px and under, so your css is fine and this will have nothing to do with angular. I am sure whatever it is you read is for some other usage

Comment: If you want to use more complicated responsive queries in angular, you may check out [this](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). It is really powerful if you don't want to touch CSS at all. Check out their [demo](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) too

Comment: A similar one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034573/ngif-hide-some-content-on-mobile-screen-angular-4

Comment: Also watch out if you have pages you need to be compatible with SSR (server side rendering). Even if you're not planning on making your entire site SSR compatible it's well worth it for landing pages and SEO. But you'll probably have to rethink a lot about how your site works, and it's certainly easier to do it from the start.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [angular/breakpoints-angular-cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview)

follow these steps

on the terminal

```
npm install @angular/cdk
```

Then import the layout module and and add it to your NgModule’s list of imports

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LayoutModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

right after you can use it in your component, just import these classes from  `@angular/cdk/layout`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public showContainer: boolean;
  constructor(public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpointObserver
      .observe(['(min-width: 400px)'])
      .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
        if (state.matches) {
          this.showContainer = true;
        } else {
          this.showContainer = false;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Check [the docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) it is a simple API

!! Attention to the new angular version, there is a better way of doing it !!

> **UPDATE IF YOU'RE USING A NEWER VERSION OF ANGULAR, THERE IS A CONSTANT TO HELP WITH THE SCREEN SIZE IDENTIFICATION**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
// NEW Breakpoints CONSTANT
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public showContainerInTablet: boolean;
  public showContainerInHandset: boolean;
  constructor(public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpointObserver
      .observe([
        Breakpoints.TabletPortrait,
        Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape
      ])
      .subscribe((state ) => {
        const breakpoints = state.breakpoints;
        this.showContainerInHandset = false;
        this.showContainerInTablet = false;
        if (breakpoints[Breakpoints.TabletPortrait]) {
         this.showContainerInTablet = true;
         console.log("screens matches TabletPortrait");
        }
        else if (breakpoints[Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape]) {
         this.showContainerInHandset = true;
         console.log("screens matches HandsetLandscape");
       } 
      });
  }
}
```

Check the tutorial on [angular website](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-responsive-design/)

Comment: Does it use Window underneath?  Will this work while using Angular Universal on the server side i.e. when Platform is NOT browser ?

Answer (score 7):

Angular flex layout is better solution for this. You wouldn't need media queries and it has special responsive feature to show and hide for example

fxShow: This markup specifies if its host element should be displayed (or not)

```
<div fxShow [fxShow.xs]="isVisibleOnMobile()"></div>
```

fxHide: This markup specifies if its host element should NOT be displayed

```
<div fxHide [fxHide.gt-sm]="isVisibleOnDesktop()"></div>
```

No need to write lot of css and it's very compatible with angular material.
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Comment: I don't know about "better", but I really love the simplicity of Flex Layout.

Comment: It also has a server module for server side rendering, which actually generates media queries (since the SSR page needs to be static and can't use things like *ngIf).

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Angular 15, flex layout is deprecated and will not be maintained anymore. So the accepted answer is the "better" solution these days

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following base class and have found it works well.

```js
import { HostBinding, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaObserver } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class MediaQueryClassBaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @HostBinding('class.xl') private xl: boolean;
    @HostBinding('class.lg') private lg: boolean;
    @HostBinding('class.md') private md: boolean;
    @HostBinding('class.sm') private sm: boolean;
    @HostBinding('class.xs') private xs: boolean;

    private mediaObserverSubscription: Subscription | undefined = undefined;

    constructor(protected readonly mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.mediaObserverSubscription)
            return;
        this.mediaObserverSubscription = this.mediaObserver.media$.subscribe(x => {
            this.xl = x.mqAlias == 'xl';
            this.lg = x.mqAlias == 'lg';
            this.md = x.mqAlias == 'md';
            this.sm = x.mqAlias == 'sm';
            this.xs = x.mqAlias == 'xs';
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (!this.mediaObserverSubscription)
            return;
        this.mediaObserverSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.mediaObserverSubscription = undefined;
    }
}
```

If you inherit (extend) your component from this class, the host element of your component will have a class added to it with the media query alias.
For example...

```
<app-search-bar class="some-class" _nghost-c5 ...>
```

...will become...

```
<app-search-bar class="some-class lg" _nghost-c5 ...>
```

Note the added media query alias 'lg' which will change according to the window size. This makes it easy to add responsive styles to each media size by
wrapping the size-specific styles in your component's SCSS files.
Like this...

```
:host-context(.sm, .md) { // styles specific to both sm and md media sizes
    .header {
        padding: 6px;
        width: 420px;
    }
}

:host-context(.lg, .xl) { // styles specific to both lg and xl media sizes
    .header {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 640px;
    }
}
```

I've put the full file on my gist https://gist.github.com/NickStrupat/b80bda11daeea06a1a67d2d9c41d4993

Answer (score 0):

Check here, it's forked solution found somewhere on internet with my customization, but it works for me (not only hiding element with display:none, but removing if from DOM - like *ngIf works)

````
    import {
        Input,
        Directive,
        TemplateRef,
        ViewContainerRef,
        OnDestroy,
        ChangeDetectorRef
    } from '@angular/core';

    /**
     * How to use this directive?
     *
     * ```
     * 
     *     Div element will exist only when media query matches, and created/destroyed when the viewport size changes.
     * 
     * ```
     */
    @Directive({
        selector: '[mqIf]'
    })
    export class MqIfDirective implements OnDestroy {
        private prevCondition: boolean = null;
        i = 0;

        private mql: MediaQueryList;
        private mqlListener: (mql: MediaQueryList) => void;   // reference kept for cleaning up in ngOnDestroy()
        constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
                    private templateRef: TemplateRef,
                    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        }

        /**
         * Called whenever the media query input value changes.
         */
        @Input()
        set mqIf(newMediaQuery: string) {
            if (!this.mql) {
                this.mql = window.matchMedia(newMediaQuery);

                /* Register for future events */
                this.mqlListener = (mq) => {
                    this.onMediaMatchChange(mq.matches);
                };
                this.mql.addListener(this.mqlListener);
            }

            this.onMediaMatchChange(this.mql.matches);
        }

        ngOnDestroy() {
            this.mql.removeListener(this.mqlListener);
            this.mql = this.mqlListener = null;
        }

        private onMediaMatchChange(matches: boolean) {
            if (matches && !this.prevCondition) {
                this.prevCondition = true;
                this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            } else if (!matches && this.prevCondition) {
                this.prevCondition = false;
                this.viewContainer.clear();
            }

            /**
             * Infinitive loop when we fire detectChanges during initialization
             * (first run on that func)
             */
            if (this.i > 0) {
                this.ref.detectChanges();
            }
            else
                this.i++;
        }
    }
````

[See here](https://gist.github.com/divisble/059f1a972ed2b9a0b0c099b6abc5511e)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -5):

```css
.container{
  background-color : powderblue;
  height : 50px;
  width : 100%
}

@media (max-width: 400px){
    .container{
        display: flex;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how this answers the question.