# how do we adjust the layout on different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="settings-admin-page-container">
    <div class="page-content flex-column">
      <mat-card class="mb-18px tenant-mat-card-centered">
        <!-- <img class="map-pin custom-pin" src="{{mapMarkerIconSingleProperty}}" /> -->
        <div class="settings-admin-page-content-form-container">
          <div fxLayoutAlign="center"> 
            <span style="padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom:15px;" class="cofirmation-text">{{configurations.INSPECTION_TENANT_ACKNOWLEDGE_CONFIRMATION.label}}</span>
          </div>
          <div fxLayoutAlign="center"> 
            <span style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:30px;" class="vendors-visit">Please confirm that you acknowledged our vendor’s visit between March 2, 2022 - March 7, 2022 Morning (8 AM - 12 PM). Thank you!</span>
          </div>
          <span style="padding-top: 24px;" class="procedure-text">{{configurations.INSPECTION_TENANT_ACKNOWLEDGE_Q1.label}}</span>
          <mat-form-field class="input-field-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>{{configurations.INSPECTION_TENANT_ACKNOWLEDGE_INPUT.label}}</mat-label>
              <textarea 
                name="A"
                matInput
                class="resize-none"
                [rows]="5"
                >
              </textarea>
            <mat-error>This is a required field.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <span style="padding-top: 24px;" class="procedure-text">{{configurations.INSPECTION_TENANT_ACKNOWLEDGE_Q2.label}}</span>
        
          <mat-form-field class="input-field-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>{{configurations.INSPECTION_TENANT_ACKNOWLEDGE_INPUT.label}}</mat-label>
              <textarea 
              name="B"
              matInput
              class="resize-none"
              [rows]="5"
              >
            </textarea>
            <mat-error>This is a required field.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
            <span style="padding-top: 24px;" class="procedure-text">{{configurations.INSPECTION_TENANT_ACKNOWLEDGE_Q3.label}}</span>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;">
              <span class="secondary-text">{{configurations.INSPECTION_TENANT_ACKNOWLEDGE_Q3.label2}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
 .tenant-mat-card-centered{
    margin-left: 565px;
    margin-right: 565px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
  }

  .procedure-text {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 143%;
    letter-spacing: 0.15px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  }

  .input-field-width {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .secondary-text {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 143%;
    letter-spacing: 0.15px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .user-card {
    margin-top:20px
  }

  .cofirmation-text{
    font-family: 'Manrope';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 143%;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  }

  .vendors-visit {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 143%;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.15px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)
  }

  .custom-pin {
    padding-top: 30px;
    width:150px;
  }
```

This looks fine at 1920x1080:
[image]

but at a lower resolution such as 1280x721, it's messed up:
[image]

How can I fix this so that the layout adjusts to the resolution?

Comment: Hi Jerum. That first image looks significantly smaller in width than 1280 pixels. How do you want your content to look on smaller widths? Do you want the text to align to the left? Do you want title words to break onto multiple lines with a hyphen? Do you want font size to shrink?

Comment: Hi Sir , If how it looks on bigger or large reso Sir then it should look the same on lower reso

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using proper CSS media queries in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628220/using-proper-css-media-queries-in-angular)

Comment: A website should adapt to fit the screen size and look *good* on any device rather than *the same* on every device

Comment: I strongly suggest you take [This course](https://courses.kevinpowell.co/conquering-responsive-layouts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media queries are exactly what you need, just as the other contributors have provided. But when working with media queries, make sure you have the appropriate HTML tag to actually get them working:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This tag essentially tells the browser how to scale your content, giving the content the ability to fit and grow/shrink with the page size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries to do this! this is a super simple example. In this case, when the screen's width is below 600px, the body background color with be green. If it goes above that, it will be blue. W3schools is an excellent resource for this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      body {
        background-color: green;
      }
    }
body{
    background-color: blue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

by using css media queries. That will help you to adjust to different screen sizes

Comment: This is a great comment, but not enough detail for an answer on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to achieve this.

**Example :**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    /*Tablets [601px -> 1200px]*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    /*Big smartphones [426px -> 600px]*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px){
    /*Small smartphones [325px -> 425px]*/
}
```

Here I'm attaching some great sources where you can learn how to make responsive web using media queries.

1. [Angular 13 How to write media queries in component styles?](https://www.cloudhadoop.com/angular-media-query-styles/)
2. [Responsive Angular Components](https://indepth.dev/posts/1383/responsive-angular)
3. [Beginner's guide to media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

1- you can use Media Queries something like this :
[In this example, the container element is set to display as a grid with two columns when the screen width is greater than 600px, and as a block element when the screen width is less than 600px.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ra7r.png)

2- Flexible Grid-based Layout

3 - Relative Units of Measurement
[In this example, the container element will take up 80% of the available width, regardless of the screen size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3KO8.png)

you can visit this link for more detail : https://codeanystuff.com/responsive-design-how-to-create-websites-that-adapt-to-different-screen-sizes-and-resolutions/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33729889)